# How do you export all Customers Data from Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

How is it possible through SQL Query?

Comment: Yes it is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Through Prestashop admin panel, it’s not possible to export all customers data, so you need to write custom SQL query to select all customer data in PHPMYADMIN and export CSV sheet.

Using following query you can select all customers who are having addresses.

```html
select ps_customer.id_customer, ps_customer.email, ps_customer.firstname,
ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.passwd, ps_customer.company,
ps_customer.birthday, ps_customer.newsletter,
ps_address.id_country, ps_address.id_state, ps_address.address1, ps_address.address2,
ps_address.postcode, ps_address.city, ps_address.phone, ps_address.vat_number
from ps_customer INNER JOIN ps_address
ON ps_customer.id_customer=ps_address.id_customer;
```

Using following query you can select all customers who are not having addresses.

```html
SELECT id_customer, email, firstname, lastname, passwd, company, birthday, newsletter
FROM ps_customer WHERE id_customer NOT IN (SELECT id_customer FROM ps_address);
```

**Customize your query based on your need of customer attributes.**

Happy reading! :)